# Java - Keytool - Import of certificate fails due to trustcacerts flag

Tags: java, certificate, keytool, jks

My cacerts' store type is: **PKCS12**

I'm running these commands:

```
keytool -server -export -alias certumca -keystore /opt/jre-1.7.0_72_FIPS/lib/security/cacerts -keypass changeit -storepass changeit -file ca_temp_cer.crt
keytool -v -trustcacerts -import -alias sbl_test_cert -file ca_temp_cer.crt -keystore /opt/jre-1.7.0_72_FIPS/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -storetype PKCS12
```

And they fail with this exception:

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.getCacertsKeyStore(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(Unknown Source)
```

if I remove the **trustcacerts** flag, the import succeeds.

When looking at the keytool.java code (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/security/tools/KeyTool.java#3478), I see that when using the trustcacerts flag - cacerts always opened with the JKS format, so no wonder my command fails.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Well, why did you change the type of cacerts in the first place? I am not sure if this is even worth reporting to Oracle as a bug in keytool, because they will just say that it is not allowed to change the type of cacerts. If you remove -trustcacerts, then the import succeeds because "certumca" is a root certificate (i.e. no trust check possible/necessary).

Comment: @Omikron I needed to change it since I'm using SSL-J

Comment: @Omikron (Please ignore my comment above...) JKS keystores cannot be loaded in FIPS-140 mode. Only PKCS12 key stores. Therefore - I needed to change it.

Comment: Oh, you are using the BSAFE libraries, I see. There are ways to detect the type of a keystore and in theory keytool could do this at the code position in your link, but - as you have already found out - it doesn't...